# How to use Diagnostic Tools for MAUI app on Android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, maui, diagnostics

I am familiar with the Diagnostic Tools for .NET applications, and I am trying to use it to debug a MAUI application running on Android. However the Diagnostic Tools window shows:

> The Diagnostic Tools window does not support the current debugging
> configuration.

How can I trace memory/cpu usage in a MAUI app in the context of running on an Android physical device ? Is that possible, or is there another recommended tool for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Android Studio** to trace memory/cpu usage of your application.

First of all, you can refer to the official document about [Inspect your app's memory usage with Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler).

And then, you can still use the Visual Studio to debug the Maui application on the physical android device but trace the memory/cpu usage of your application in the Android Studio.

1. Attach your application debug process to the android studio profile.

[image]

1. Trace memory/cpu usage of your application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Sentry

It supports a wide range of languages and platforms.

I use for exception handling in my .Net MAUI apps (which are not commerical, and just for my use), but I know that it also has performance tracking capability which you might find useful.

More details here:

https://sentry.io/for/dot-net/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F&platform=sentry.dotnet.maui